# Can I make a function available in every controller in angular?

Tags: angularjs, function, global

If I have a utility function `foo` that I want to be able to call from anywhere inside of my `ng-app` declaration. Is there someway I can make it globally accessible in my module setup or do I need to add it to the scope in every controller?

Comment: I am not 100% sure about this, but there is a chance you can also define it on your module like this: `module.value('myFunc', function(a){return a;});` and then inject it by name in your controllers. (If one wants to avoid making a service)

Comment: Meaning that I have to add it to every controller manually. $rootScope is the way to go for what I wanted to do almost 2 years ago =)

Comment: OK. :) I just use directives with isolated scope more often than plain controllers and I have to inject everything anyway. I like the modular code style that this provides. Also, you don't have to mess with parent scopes in any way and you don't have to search much for where your scope variables come from. :)

Answer (score 293, accepted):

You basically have two options, either define it as a service, or place it on your root scope. I would suggest that you make a service out of it to avoid polluting the root scope. You create a service and make it available in your controller like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.factory('myService', function() {
        return {
            foo: function() {
                alert("I'm foo!");
            }
        };
    });

    myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'myService', function($scope, myService) {
        $scope.callFoo = function() {
            myService.foo();
        }
    }]);
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <button ng-click="callFoo()">Call foo</button>
</body>
</html>
```

If that's not an option for you, you can add it to the root scope like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.run(function($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.globalFoo = function() {
            alert("I'm global foo!");
        };
    });

    myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

    }]);
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <button ng-click="globalFoo()">Call global foo</button>
</body>
</html>
```

That way, all of your templates can call `globalFoo()` without having to pass it to the template from the controller.

Comment: In the first solution, what if there are tons of `foo()` functions? Making a `$scope.callFoo()` wrapper for every one of them is too much work. How can I *"attach"* all functions of a library into scope so that it can be used in the template? I have a big unit conversion library that I want it to be available on my template.

Comment: My question as well. I tried this out and it works: you can "attach" it by saying `$scope.callFoo =  myService.foo;` in place of creating a new wrapper in each place you want to use it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was wondering how to make available a change language function throughout my app and $rootScope did the job. I wanted to keep the translation module apart from the application so I can plug it into other apps as well.

Comment: I'd suggest use an Angular Value rather than a Factory for this specific case unless you plan on having multiple functions within a service.  If it's only one function, make it a Value.

Comment: I got Error: [$injector:unpr]

Comment: define it as a service (global or common service) which then you can invoke in every controller since it has been injected by service factory. :)

Answer (score 54):

You can also combine them I guess:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

        myApp.factory('myService', function() {
            return {
                foo: function() {
                    alert("I'm foo!");
                }
            };
        });

        myApp.run(function($rootScope, myService) {
            $rootScope.appData = myService;
        });

        myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

        }]);

    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <button ng-click="appData.foo()">Call foo</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this should be the correct answer, justified by the answer of @Praym. It doesn't make sense specify a service dependency in 10 different controllers.

Comment: Can the service include methods/functions which can CRUD properties/variables in the `$rootScope`?

Answer (score 45):

Though the first approach is advocated as 'the angular like' approach, I feel this adds overheads.

Consider if I want to use this myservice.foo function in 10 different controllers. I will have to  specify this 'myService' dependency and then $scope.callFoo scope property in all ten of them. This is simply a repetition and somehow violates the DRY principle.

Whereas, if I use the $rootScope approach, I specify this global function gobalFoo only once and it will be available in all my future controllers, no matter how many.

Comment: There may be some value in the controllers 'documenting' where they get that global service call.  If you were you yank one of your controllers into another application it would be less clear where that global function came from.  I hear recognize your argument though.

Comment: It only has to be put on the scope if you need to call it from the view. In the controller, you can call it directly from the service.

Comment: This is a comment not an answer

Comment: $rootScope variable always null on page refresh in that case you will not get the function. That's why its good to inject the service and use its reference in application.

Answer (score 4):

AngularJs has "**Services**" and "**Factories**" just for problems like yours.These are used to have something global **between Controllers, Directives, Other Services or any other angularjs components**..You can defined functions, store data, make calculate functions or whatever you want inside **Services** and use them in AngularJs Components as **Global**.like

```
angular.module('MyModule', [...])
  .service('MyService', ['$http', function($http){
    return {
       users: [...],
       getUserFriends: function(userId){
          return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/api/user/friends/' + userId
          });
       }
       ....
    }
  }])
```

if you need more

[Find More About Why We Need AngularJs Services and Factories](http://www.w3docs.com/snippets/angularjs/basic-knowledge-about-angularjs-services-and-factories.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit newer to Angular but what I found useful to do (and pretty simple) is I made a global script that I load onto my page before the local script with global variables that I need to access on all pages anyway. In that script, I created an object called "globalFunctions" and added the functions that I need to access globally as properties. e.g. `globalFunctions.foo = myFunc();`. Then, in each local script, I wrote `$scope.globalFunctions = globalFunctions;` and I instantly have access to any function I added to the globalFunctions object in the global script.

This is a bit of a workaround and I'm not sure it helps you but it definitely helped me as I had many functions and it was a pain adding all of them to each page.

Comment: I'm just curious why the downvotes? I am new and would like to know from the pros.

Comment: Seems like a working solution to me.  The only thing I would advocate, in order to make sure your scope is sufficiently isolated, is to create a global root Javascript utility class and hang your utility methods off of that so that you don't accidentally step on some other function name in the vast sea of things injected by Angular.

Comment: One thing to note, and maybe why this is downvoted, you could only use those functions in your templates, not your .ts modules as your function calls would not resolve at compile time.  This is the reason for doing it the "angular" way.  But, if you just want to add decorators and such to your templates, a global utility file is simple and fine.