# Access javascript built-ins inside an angularjs expression

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, expression

I'm a beginner at Angularjs and I would like to know how can I use javascript built-ins like `Date` or `Array` in expressions. It seems weird to add them like this `$scope.Array = Array` in every controller.

Comment: Why would you add them to the scope like that anyway? Why would you need those things in your expressions? Seems like that's doing work in the view that's probably unnecessary.

Comment: I'd like to have a function that does exactly what Date does and another function that does exactly what Array does. Those functions are pretty useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: In response to your comment below, I would just add a little change to the way you have done it as I personally like to remove as much logic as possible from the view.

JavaScript

```
$scope.numItems = 5;
$scope.range = Array($scope.numItems);
```

HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="i in range track by $index">
    <td align="center">{{$index}}</td>
```

Comment: But it's weird, adding it to every controller. Code duplication. Doesn't seem very angularjs to me. Also, I wanted the funtions Date and Array, not instances. So that in the expression I can write {{Array(5)}} and {{Date()}} or maybe {{Date(2013, 0, 1)}} (in this case it should call new Date(2013, 0, 1) with "new"). The Array example is useful for <li ng-repeat="i in Array(5) track by $index">

Comment: @Ella Shar But if you write {{Array(5)}} what does 'Array' refer to? Never mind AngularJS, what does Array(5) in JavaScript mean? Wouldn't you normally write var arr = [...]; var x = arr[5]?

Comment: Array(5) creates an empty array of length 5. This is useful in angularjs for iterating over to duplicate something a given number of times.

Comment: try this  `{{Date(2013, 0, 1) | date}}`, you can use built in's without having to define them on $scope

Comment: @EllaShar Sorry, I meant what would Array(5) contain? It is empty so {{Array(5)}} doesn't make sense, especially as {{}} should be accessing an element of the array.

Comment: @harish I wrote <p>{{Date(2013, 0, 1) | date}}</p> and the page was blank.

Comment: @camden_kid I now have a controller with `$scope.range = Array;` in it. In the scope of that controller, I do `<tr ng-repeat="i in range(10) track by $index">` and it creates a loop of 10. So I can do `<td align="center">{{$index}}</td>` inside to give a number to each row.

Comment: That's nice but not really what I asked for. I want a function that can be used over many controllers. Also I'm not sure if removing that much logic is good, the HTML should be indicative. What do you think, since I'm just a beginner?

Comment: @EllaShar I think I understand now. You should use a service that you can inject into any controller - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services. I still think one should remove all logic from the view as this complies with the MVC principles of AngularJS.

Comment: And then I'll have to inject that service to every controller and use something like $scope.range = myService? I thought about that but for a task as simple as "$scope.Array = Array" a service is too much. Isn't there a way for me to only inject once?

Comment: @EllaShar You can just use myService without assigning it to a variable, e.g. myService.myFunc(). The other option would be to create a function on $rootScope, e.g. $rootScope.myFunc = function(); You can then inject $rootScope and use $rootScope.myFunc(). Lastly, if you really don't want to inject you could just create a global JavsScript function.

Comment: @camden_kid I declared the following service: `.service('ser', function(){this.range = Array;});` and then used it: `ser.range(5)`. It works when I inject it and assign it to `$scope` in the controller but it doesn't work if I don't.
creating a function on `$rootScope` works, thanks! without any injection, I just added `app.run(function($rootScope){$rootScope.range = Array;});` Is this an "angularjs" way or is it ugly? Also I tried creating a global JS function and it didn't work, are you sure I can access a global function from the HTML? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just saw this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025979/can-i-make-a-function-available-in-every-controller-in-angular which is really helpful

Comment: @EllaShar I think that question and the answers is what you are looking for. I prefer not to use $rootScope as it is like creating global variables/functions. You may want to delete this question. It will remove my answer but that's not a problem.

Comment: I don't see a reason to deleted it, I googled before asking and since I didn't really know what to ask, I got no answers. And maybe someone will have the same question as mine, who knows.  Thanks again