# Make a default function for all controllers Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

Is there a possibility to make a custom function like you can do with PHP? For example:

```
<?php

function helloWorld(){
  return 'Hello world!';
}
```

I would like to call a function like [[myFunction(parameter)]]

EDIT:
I want to make a JavaScript function that returns a value. In example:

```
function helloWorld(){
    return 'Hello from the Func!';
}
```

When a angular template gets called, i want to call that function like: {{helloWorld()}}, no matter what scope or controller I'm using.

So, I want `helloWorld()` to be available on any scope.

The thing is: if you bind it to the scope, you can call it only when that specific controller is loaded... I want to call this function everywhere

Comment: Could you please elaborate, because I can't figure out what you're asking, and what you want to achieve.

Comment: So you want a function that is run each time any controller is loaded or once at the beginning of the app?

Comment: Actually i found a solution for my issue. The word i was searching for was Global Function. I can add my function to the rootScope and call it from there... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025979/can-i-make-a-function-available-in-every-controller-in-angular