# How to show another scope value in view corresponding to other value?

Tags: angularjs

I am newbie to angular. I have two scope variables i.e,`$scope.jsonData` and `$scope.dbdatas`. I want to show value from `$scope.jsonData` corresponding to `$scope.dbdatas.name`. Please check my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/td8rm6dy/33/). I have mentioned my desire output in the code.

View:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-6" style="padding: 10px" ng-repeat="dbdata in dbdatas">
      <div>
       {{dbdata.name}} : <span class="list_text">{{dbdata.value}}</span>   
                            <!--something like {{dbdata.name}} : <span show-value class="list_text">{{dbdata.value}}</span>-->

       </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('TestCtrl',function($scope){
$scope.jsonData=[{"_id":"56f90a9a51ec8f20e786a9e7","name":"Eleget","options":[{"key":"Y","value":"Once"},{"key":"M","value":"More than once"}]},{"_id":"56f90a9a51fs8f20e786a9e7","name":"MoliRet","options":[{"key":"L","value":"Let"},{"key":"R","value":"Ret"}]}];

$scope.dbdatas=[{name:'MoliRet',value:'L'},{name:'MoliRet',value:'R'},{name:'Eleget',value:'M'}];
});

/*app.directive('showValue',function(){
return{
    restrict:'A',
  link:function(scope,ele,attr){

  }
}
});*/
```

> **Current Output**
>
> MoliRet : L
>
> MoliRet : R
>
> Eleget : M
>
> **Desire Output**
>
> MoliRet: Let
>
> MoliRet: Ret
>
> Eleget: More than once

Comment: whats not working here please gives us proper inputs

Comment: What you want is not clear. Please clarify what you actually want.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/td8rm6dy/10/ is working, not clear your questions

Answer (score 1):

You can use angular.ForEach to match data from both scope variables and push the data to an array $scope. Please take a look at the solution below.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-6" style="padding: 10px" ng-repeat="dbdata in dbdatas">
            <div>
               {{dbdata.name}} : <span class="list_text">{{dbdata.value}}</span>   
           </div>
       </div>
      <div ng-repeat="expect1 in expectations">{{expect1.name}}: {{expect1.value}}</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

---

```
$scope.dbdatas=[{name:'MoliRet',value:'L'},{name:'MoliRet',value:'R'},{name:'Eleget',value:'M'}];
   $scope.expectations= [];
   angular.forEach($scope.dbdatas,function(value1){
     angular.forEach($scope.jsonData,function(value2){
     if(value1.name == value2.name){
       angular.forEach(value2.options,function(value3){
         if(value3.key == value1.value){
           $scope.expectations.push({
           "name" : value2.name,
           "value": value3.value});
          }
       });
     }
   });
});
```

Expected output will be

MoliRet: Let

MoliRet: Ret

Eleget: More than once

Comment: can we use here `directive` to achieve this desire output. `something like {{dbdata.name}} : <span show-value="dbdata" class="list_text"></span>`

Answer (score 1):

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kadgw0cr/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
     <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
           <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-6" style="padding: 10px" ng-repeat="item in jsonData">
             <div ng-repeat='option in item.options'>
                <div ng-show="isInArray(option.key)">
                    {{item.name}}: {{option.value}}  
                </div>
             </div>
           </div>
      </div> 
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('TestCtrl',function($scope){

$scope.isInArray = function(key){
  var returnValue = false;    
  for(var i=0;i<$scope.dbdatas.length;i++){
    if($scope.dbdatas[i].value==key){
      returnValue = true;      
      break;
    }
    
  }
  
  return returnValue
 
}

$scope.jsonData=[{"_id":"56f90a9a51ec8f20e786a9e7","name":"Eleget","options":[{"key":"Y","value":"Once"},{"key":"M","value":"More than once"}]},{"_id":"56f90a9a51fs8f20e786a9e7","name":"MoliRet","options":[{"key":"L","value":"Let"},{"key":"R","value":"Ret"}]}];

$scope.dbdatas=[{name:'MoliRet',value:'L'},{name:'MoliRet',value:'R'},{name:'Eleget',value:'M'}];
});
```

**Output:**

> Eleget: More than once
>
> MoliRet: Let
>
> MoliRet: Ret

Hope that solve your problem.

Comment: can we use here `directive` to achieve this desire output. `something like {{dbdata.name}} : <span show-value="dbdata" class="list_text"></span>`

Comment: Please explain what do you actually want. You have expected data on your hand. Why do you want to use directive?

Comment: Because i need to use this logic in many controllers. That's why i want to use directive. Otherwise i have to define `isInArray` function in all controllers, i think that is not good approach.

Comment: You just want to replace only `isInArray` with a directive right?

Comment: You basically have two options, either define it as a service, or place it on your root scope. [Have a look at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15026440/3186722)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you have to store a unique options table in one json and use angular custom service filter to handle the relative key 'look at the plunker'. you can use this custom filter in any controller and view.

Here is custom filter

```
app.filter('myFilter', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
  return function (data, param) {
    var output = $filter('filter')(data, {key:param},true);
    return (param && output.length) ? output[0].value : '';
  };
}]);
```

Here is a working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/5v9IFQUAMHdhq7MbvHTj?p=preview) 
.Hope that help.