# Can I create global function with $window and call it in controllers in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, window, single-page-application

I want to create a global function like:

```
function CheckAuthorization($window)
{
    if($cookieStore.get('token')=='')
        $window.location.href = '/login';
}
```

and call it everywhere. Is this possible? The above code is not working.

Comment: This is my service      `app.factory('myService', function () {
        return {
            CheckAuthorization: function () {
                
                if ($cookieStore.get('token') == '')
                    $window.location.href = '/login';
            }
        };
    });`   call this in controller like this :    `app.controller('ContactController', function ($scope, myService) {
    myService.CheckAuthorization();
    $scope.message = "ContactController";
});`     but i am getting an error like  as

Comment: The answer to the link above should work for you. There is a very simple example for creating a service to hold the function or a simple example to add it to the root scope. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15026440/4084574 You should not have any problems adapting this.

Comment: @mhatch actually i am getting problem in this line     `$window.location.href = '/login';`

Comment: Have you tried using Angular `$location`? https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Comment: @mhatch yes its not working and then i used this  `$window.location.href = '/login'`..

Comment: Try logging out the contents of `$window.location.href` to see if it matches what you expect? My suspicion might be that it involves the angular single page routing. If you create a plunker I can look at it.

Comment: `/login` is just a route to a view. So what you really want to do is change the view, not reload the whole page.

Comment: @mhatch i am checking for cookie `if ($cookieStore.get('token') == '')`  and if cookie is null then redirect to the login  view